# Prisma + MongoDB -> Replica set

Tags: mongodb, localhost, prisma, mongodb-replica-set

Error `Invalid "prisma.user.create()". Prisma needs to perform transactions, which requires your MongoDB server to be run as a replica set.`

I used Nx ([nx.dev](https://nx.dev)) with MongoDB/Express with Prisma.

Answer (score 8):

## Local Instance with docker

An easy to use [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/prismagraphql/mongo-single-replica) is available that creates a single instance replica

- Pull the image with `docker pull prismagraphql/mongo-single-replica:5.0.3`
- Run the image with

```bash
docker run --name mongo \
      -p 27017:27017 \
      -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME="monty" \
      -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD="pass" \
      -d prismagraphql/mongo-single-replica:5.0.3
```

- The connection URL should like this

```
DATABASE_URL="mongodb://monty:pass@localhost:27017/db_name?authSource=admin&directConnection=true"
```

You must provide authSource=admin option otherwise authentication will fail

## MongoDB Atlas

- Create a free cluster with all default values
- Note the username, password and the hostname
- The URL should look like this

```
DATABASE_URL="mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster_name.random_string.net/db_name?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Note that the official [documentaion](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mongodb) currently follows the previous format used for the local instance but here it does not include the port number and has the +srv suffix, without which I ran into some problems.

If you want use the format used in the documentation then you must provide the option ssl=true and for the hostname you have to use the primary cluster which looks like random_string.mongodb.net:27017, which you can find in the overview tab after clicking in your cluster name

Comment: The only solution worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, after long hours of facing continuous issues in connecting Prisma and MongoDB(local), we have 3 ways of fixing this.
You have to use either **Docker** or **MongoDB Atlas**.

Docker - [Docker](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/blob/main/docker/mongodb_replica/Dockerfile)
MongoDB Atlas - [MongoDB Replica](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)

Ps. Your MongoDB URL env should be looking like this -> **`mongodb://localhost:27017/<your-db-name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`**.

I decided to finally choose the option 3.
Jumping from MongoDB to PostgreSQL which don't have any replica issues, but no noSQL :)

Comment: I faced this issue too, any ideas why it can't work with just prisma and local MongoDB without docker ro MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: @user3226932 They are working on this probably and there is a solution which I didn't try. [Github Issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/11860#issuecomment-1044695589). Prisma docs is suggesting to use either atlas/Docker for the same error [PrismaDocs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mongodb#error-transactions-are-not-supported-by-this-deployment).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "prisma": "2.26.0" and "@prisma/client": "2.26.0" instead of your current version. They don`t need a replica set.
Also you have to use @default(dbgenerated()) instead of @default(auto()) both with "npx prisma@2.26.0 generate" for this old version.